# QXmlStreamReader not parsing xml file

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I'm having trouble reading the follwing Xml file:

```
<ArrayOfScore xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Score><GameKey>201610629</GameKey><SeasonType>1</SeasonType><Season>2016</Season><Week>6</Week><Date>2016-10-13T20:25:00</Date><AwayTeam>DEN</AwayTeam><HomeTeam>SD</HomeTeam><AwayScore>13</AwayScore><HomeScore>21</HomeScore><Channel i:nil="true"/><PointSpread>3.0</PointSpread><OverUnder>44.5</OverUnder><Quarter>F</Quarter><TimeRemaining i:nil="true"/><Possession i:nil="true"/><Down i:nil="true"/><Distance i:nil="true"/><YardLine i:nil="true"/><YardLineTerritory i:nil="true"/><RedZone i:nil="true"/><AwayScoreQuarter1>0</AwayScoreQuarter1><AwayScoreQuarter2>3</AwayScoreQuarter2><AwayScoreQuarter3>0</AwayScoreQuarter3><AwayScoreQuarter4>10</AwayScoreQuarter4><AwayScoreOvertime>0</AwayScoreOvertime><HomeScoreQuarter1>7</HomeScoreQuarter1><HomeScoreQuarter2>3</HomeScoreQuarter2><HomeScoreQuarter3>9</HomeScoreQuarter3><HomeScoreQuarter4>2</HomeScoreQuarter4><HomeScoreOvertime>0</HomeScoreOvertime><HasStarted>true</HasStarted><IsInProgress>false</IsInProgress><IsOver>true</IsOver><Has1stQuarterStarted>true</Has1stQuarterStarted><Has2ndQuarterStarted>true</Has2ndQuarterStarted><Has3rdQuarterStarted>true</Has3rdQuarterStarted><Has4thQuarterStarted>true</Has4thQuarterStarted><IsOvertime>false</IsOvertime><DownAndDistance i:nil="true"/><QuarterDescription>Final</QuarterDescription><StadiumID>14</StadiumID><LastUpdated>2016-10-17T14:27:48</LastUpdated><GeoLat>32.783188</GeoLat><GeoLong>-117.119439</GeoLong><ForecastTempLow>58</ForecastTempLow><ForecastTempHigh>76</ForecastTempHigh><ForecastDescription>Sunny</ForecastDescription><ForecastWindChill>70</ForecastWindChill><ForecastWindSpeed>14</ForecastWindSpeed><AwayTeamMoneyLine>-160</AwayTeamMoneyLine><HomeTeamMoneyLine>140</HomeTeamMoneyLine><Canceled>false</Canceled><Closed>true</Closed><LastPlay i:nil="true"/><StadiumDetails><StadiumID>14</StadiumID><Name>Qualcomm Stadium</Name><City>San Diego</City><State>CA</State><Country>USA</Country><Capacity>70561</Capacity><PlayingSurface>Grass</PlayingSurface><GeoLat>32.783188</GeoLat><GeoLong>-117.119439</GeoLong></StadiumDetails></Score></ArrayOfScore>
```

I use the following code to try to read the elements:

```
QFile testxml("./test.xml");
if(testxml.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QXmlStreamReader XMLData(&testxml);
    while(!XMLData.atEnd() && !XMLData.hasError()) {
        XMLData.readNext();
        qDebug() << XMLData.readElementText();
        if(XMLData.isStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << XMLData.name();
            qDebug() << XMLData.readElementText();
        }
    }
}
```

But I only get two empty strings.

I have tried reading another Xml file which looks very similar and which is also everything in one line and I can successfully parse the elements. With this file it is somehow not working.

Does anyone have any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm suspecting `XMLData.readElementText` is your problem. The docs state: [*Convenience function to be called in case a StartElement was read. Reads until the corresponding EndElement and returns all text in-between*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText). So it will skip until the end of that element.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That was the problem. I used `readElementText(QXmlStreamReader::IncludeChildElements)` since all elements are child elements.